# what's the difference between {} and () when using filter?

Tags: scala

To filter a list using function of filter,if using `{}` it works, but if use `()` then it failed, but why?

```
scala> c
res25: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))

scala> d
res26: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))

scala> val d=b.filter{case (x,y)=> y % 2 ==0}
d: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))

scala> val d=b.filter(case (x,y)=> y % 2 ==0)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val d=b.filter(case (x,y)=> y % 2 ==0)
                  ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using a simple expression. Your first form with `{}` is a shortcut for

```
scala> d.filter({case (x,y)=> y % 2 ==0})
res177: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))
```

You can drop the `()` but not the `{}`.

**Edit**

Using `case` is not necessary. You can access the `scala.Tuple2`:

```
scala> d.filter(t => t._2 % 2 == 0)
res182: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))
```

Even shorter:

```
scala> d.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0)
res183: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (3,2), (5,4))
```

These are simple expressions that can be used as arguments for `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

This `{case (x,y)=> y % 2 ==0}` is a PartialFunction. In Scala, partial functions have to be defined inside curly braces.

When passing a partial function as argument to a method `f`, you can do `f({...})` or `f {...}`. This is the same as passing an integer to a method `g`, where you can do `g(1)` or `g 1`.